# Unity3d hdrp decal material and vertex painting as transparency

Tags: unity-game-engine, decal

I saw decal pack on youtube recently, fantasy of Rome or something like that, and they use vertex painting on decal to make some parts of it transparent. I work in hdrp pipeline, so I can use planes as decals with hdrp decal material and decal projector, and it's awesome, but is there a way to draw in transparency of plane or projected decal using Polybrush? My goal is to use one texture to get many unique decals.

Comment: You can develop a shader in shader graph I would suggest two videos please check. 1). [Unity Shader Graph: Vertex Painting Shader!](https://youtu.be/bA9BXvYfaB0) 2).[Unity Shader Graph Tutorial: Height Blended Vertex Painting.](https://youtu.be/YH1zm-Xm-Do)

Comment: Let me know if this helps

Comment: Very good tutorials, thank you!

Comment: Any time sir...

Comment: @Ankit Do you happen to know how to make any shader Graph based material work in Unity 2019.2? I can you its HDRP Lit and Decal materials, but when I create even simple PBR or Lit Graph shader with only one Color node linked to albedo - once I put material based on that shader my scene becomes black (and in runtime too) until I remove this material from object. I linked HDRP asset to Graphics settings, so that could not be the issue.

Comment: can I have to shader?

Comment: I've just created empty PBR shader, created material, applied to object and the whole scene is black. Replaced by empty HDRP Lit material, skybox and everything returned.

Comment: That is something that I've never seen before. It would be good if I can take a look at your shader.

Comment: It looks like this unity is broken, I've installed 2019.3 and shader kinda works. In 2019.2 even their sample shaders like Metal make scene black.

Comment: Ya, that might be the case.